# How to get generic type information from getAnnotatedParameterTypes() in Java 8?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8, type-annotation

It seems like `getAnnotatedParameterTypes()` returns an array of `AnnotatedType`s holding raw, rather than generic, types.  For example:

```
public <T> void genericMethod(T t) {
}

@Test
public void testAnnotatedTypes() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Method method = getClass().getMethod("genericMethod", Object.class);

    Type type = method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
    assertTrue(type instanceof TypeVariable);

    AnnotatedType annotatedType = method.getAnnotatedParameterTypes()[0];

    // This fails; annotatedType implements only AnnotatedType
    assertTrue(annotatedType instanceof AnnotatedTypeVariable);

    // This fails too; type is a TypeVariable while annotatedType.getType() is
    // Object.class
    assertEquals(type, annotatedType.getType());
}
```

What's the reason for the disagreement with `getGenericParameterTypes()`?

Comment: This is also true for `ParameterizedType`s. As far as I can tell, there's no way to get the annotation for `List<@SomeAnnotation T>` because of the same problem. Weird!

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't even gotten that far yet. That's horrible!

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks for putting a bounty on this, I was just about to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [bug report about this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039916?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel), and it has since been fixed.

There's a difference between [`Method#getGenericParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--) and `Method#getAnnotatedParameterTypes()`.

The former makes guarantees about the types it returns

> If a formal parameter type is a parameterized type, the Type object
>   returned for it must accurately reflect the actual type parameters
>   used in the source code.
>
> If a formal parameter type is a type variable or a parameterized type,
>   it is created. Otherwise, it is resolved.

while the latter doesn't, not clearly at least:

> Returns an array of `AnnotatedType` objects that represent the use of
>   types to specify formal parameter types of the method/constructor
>   represented by this `Executable`.

We have to assume that [`getAnnotatedParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getAnnotatedParameterTypes--) returns the erased types (although it may not have been intended that way). The unbounded type variable `T` is erased to `Object`. If you had `<T extends Foo>`, it would be erased to `Foo`.

As for the comments, about getting the annotation from a type argument in a method parameter, there's no way given the above. One would think it works as it does for fields.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Field field = Example.class.getField("field");
    AnnotatedParameterizedType annotatedParameterizedType = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) field
            .getAnnotatedType();

    System.out.println(annotatedParameterizedType
            .getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0].getType());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(annotatedParameterizedType
            .getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0].getAnnotations()));
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.TYPE_USE })
@interface Bar {
}

public List<@Bar String> field;
```

which prints

```
class java.lang.String
[@com.example.Example$Bar()]
```

I very much think it's a bug that needs fixing and will be following the bug report linked above.

Comment: Good find with the bug report. +1

Comment: Looks like the bug is fixed in HEAD, simple one-line change.  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/a4138f3a3432